# Custon object fields from controller not displayed using apex:outputfield in VF page

Tags: controller, salesforce, visualforce

> I am using  tag for displaying controller's custom object fields in VF page. After selecting value from picklist (which is implemented using ), I have put  tag to retreive custom object from DB in controller. Now I want to show fields of this RETREIVED object in VF page onchange of picklist value. Those value are not getting displayed.
>   I know this is very basic, please help me in clearing any silly mistake!
>
> VF Page:

```
<apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlocksection title="Attribute Details">
                <apex:tabpanel switchtype="client">
                    <apex:tab label="Script 1" id="s1" labelWidth="90px">
                        <h1>
                            Choose Script:
                        </h1>
                        <apex:selectlist value="{!selectedValue}" size="1" id="selectID">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!scriptoptions}" />
                        </apex:selectlist>
                        <br/>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="thisPanel">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setValues}" rerender="thisPanel" />
                            <apex:actionStatus startText="fetching related values..."
                                               stopText="" id="actionStatus"/>
                            <outputfield label="Executioner" value="{!valueResult.Executioner_Emp_ID__c}"/>
                            <br/>
                            <outputfield label="Planner" value="{!valueResult.Planner_Emp_ID__c}"/>
                            <br/>
                            <outputfield label="Reviewer" value="{!valueResult.Reviewer_Emp_ID__c}"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:tab>.....
```

> Controller:

```
public class ScriptAttributesController 
{

    public String setValues { get; set; }
    public List<Test_script__c> scriptListWithValues = [select name, id, Executioner__c, Planner__c, Reviewer__c from Test_Script__c];
    public static Test_Script__c valueResult {get;set;}
    public String selectedValue {get;set;}

    //public Test_Script__c returnedTestScript {get;set;}

    public void ScriptAttributesController()
    {
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getScriptoptions()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('select a value','select a value'));
        for(Test_Script__c s: scriptListWithValues )
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption(s.id,s.name));
        }
        return options;
    }

        public void setValues()
    {
        system.debug('ValueResult: '+valueResult);
        system.debug('selectedValue: '+selectedValue);
        valueResult=[select name, id, Executioner_Emp_ID__c, Planner_Emp_ID__c, Reviewer_Emp_ID__c, Iteration__c from Test_Script__c where id=:selectedValue limit 1];
        system.debug('ValueResult: '+valueResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes:

1. First one is that *apex:actionSupport* tag should be inside *apex:selectlist*. And also if you want to display current action status you should use *status* attribute in *apex:actionSupport*.
2. The other is that you should use *apex:outputfield* instead of simple *outputfield*.

Here is the fixed code:

```
<apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlocksection title="Attribute Details">
                <apex:tabpanel switchtype="client">
                    <apex:tab label="Script 1" id="s1" labelWidth="90px">
                        <h1>
                            Choose Script:
                        </h1>
                        <apex:selectlist value="{!selectedValue}" size="1" id="selectID">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!scriptoptions}" />
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setValues}" rerender="thisPanel" status="actionStatus"/>
                        </apex:selectlist>
                        <br/>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="thisPanel">
                            <apex:actionStatus startText="fetching related values..."
                                               stopText="" id="actionStatus"/>
                            <apex:outputfield label="Executioner" value="{!valueResult.Executioner_Emp_ID__c}"/>
                            <br/>
                            <apex:outputfield label="Planner" value="{!valueResult.Planner_Emp_ID__c}"/>
                            <br/>
                            <apex:outputfield label="Reviewer" value="{!valueResult.Reviewer_Emp_ID__c}"/>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </apex:tab>.....
```